# Prove $\|f\|_{L^p}$ is not equivalent to $\|f\|_{\infty}$ in $C[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Prove that in $C[a,b]$ the uniform norm is not equivalent to the $L^p$ norm for $(1\leq p < \infty)$
I am stuck on showing that the function below satifies the claim. I know that f is continuous and the uniform norm gives a finite result. Im not sure how to proceed.
In the normed linear vector space $(C[a,b],\|.\|)$ we have to find a function where the norms are not equivalent, i.e.:
$\nexists C,c C>c>0$ such that $c\|f\|_{L^p}\leq \|f\|_{\infty} \leq C\|f\|_{L^p}$
$$\|f\|_{L^p}= \left(\int_a^b \lvert\,f(t)\rvert^p d \mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}, \quad
\|f\|_\infty = \sup_{x \in [a,b]}\lvert f(x)\rvert.$$ 
Take 
$f_n(x) =\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  1-nx  & \mbox{on } x \leq 1/n \\
  0 & \mbox{on } x > 1/n
 \end{array}
\right.$

thanks for any help!

Comment: The $L^p$ norm misses an exponent $p$ or $1/p$. // You were given the functions to check. // What is the question?

Comment: Just note the $L_p$-norm of your $f_n$ is at most $1/n^{1/p}$ while the $L_\infty$-norm is $1$. With $C$ fixed, can the right hand side of your inequality hold for all $n$?  (You need to show there is no $c$, $C$ so that your inequality holds for all $f\in C[0,1]$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another example, with functions $f_n$ in $C^\infty([0,+\infty))$:
$$
f_n(x)=\mathrm e^{-nx}.$$
Then $\|f_n\|_\infty=1$ and $\|f_n\|_p=(np)^{-1/p}\to0$ hence the inequality $\|f\|_\infty\leqslant C\|f\|_p$ for every $f$ in $C^\infty([0,+\infty))$ and for some finite constant $C$ independent of $f$, is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Take $f(x)=|x-a|^{-1/2p}$. Clearly $f\in L^p[a,b]$, but $f\not\in L^\infty[a,b]$. Then take
$$
f_\delta(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
f(a+\delta) & \text{if} & x\in [a,a+\delta), \\
f(x) & \text{if} & x\in [a+\delta,b].
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Clearly, $f\delta$ belongs to both $L^p[a,b]$ and $L^\infty[a,b]$,
and 
$$
\|f_\delta\|_p\le\|f\|_p=\left(2(b-a)^{1/2}\right)^{\!1/p},
$$
while
$$
\|f_\delta\|_\infty=f_\delta(a)=\delta^{-1/2p},
$$
and hence there is no $c$ such that
$$
\|f_\delta\|_{\infty}\le c\|f_\delta\|_{p}.
$$